# Problems with activating iframes with jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, iframe

I am working on a very basic school project and have some problems with my iframes. I run some jquery code which allows me to activate iframes with a click on a div. The problem is that when i have once activated a iframe, i can't activate other iframes on top of it. 
Sidnote, the jquery is being repeated 4 times with the only change being the id, which in this case sais "#computer"

Here's the jquery and html. Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript"         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#computer').click(function(){
        if(!$('#iframe').length) {
                $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe"     src="../iframes/computer_iframe.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
    }
    });`enter code here`
});
</script>

<div class="clickable iframe activating divs">
    <div id="computer" class="computer_box"><p class="computer_text">My     Computer<p></div>
    <div id="monitor" class="monitor_box"><p class="monitor_text">My Monitor</p></div>
    <div id="keyboard" class="keyboard_box"><p class="keyboard_text">My Keyboard</p></div>
    <div id="mice" class="mice_box"><p class="mice_text">My Mice</p></div>
</div> <!--clickable iframe activating divs -->
```

The website is actually on my schools web hotel and you can see the problem here, [My website](http://www.akrawebb.se/isak/underpages/support.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it, you are only allowing the iFrame to be created if an iFrame doesn't already exist:

```
$('#computer').click(function(){
  if(!$('#iframe').length) {
    $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="../iframes/computer_iframe.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
  }
});
```

When you add the first iFrame, `$('#iframe').length` will be 1, invaliating your `if` condition. Considering you're simply *changing* the content of the iFrame, that whole conditional can be skipped -- `$('#iframeHolder').html()` will simply *replace* the content if any already exists:

```
$('#computer').click(function(){
  $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="../iframes/computer_iframe.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just marked it, im new to this forum so i didn't knew how that worked out but now it's done, thanks again.